# Does Dracula (or regular vampires) burn in sunlight if they're in bat form?

Tags: vampire, dracula

The title says it all.

Dracula (and in some/many lores, normal vampires) are capable of bat form.

What happens if a regular vampire or Dracula is exposed to sunlight in their bat form? The same burning decay, or are they capable of surviving (or surviving longer) when in bat form?

[edit] Obviously, restrict the question to lore which actually features vampires in bat form, and sunlight as an ill effect.

[edit] I'm not looking for a single answer, but a list of answers from different universes.

Comment: Dracula doesn't burn in sunlight anyway, in Bram Stoker's novel. The answer to this might vary depending on the story. Did you have a particular one in mind?

Comment: Depends on the particular lore. There are even different variants of Dracula. In the original Bram Stoker novel Dracula doesn't burn in sunlight, however in Disney's "Hotel Transylvania" Dracula does burn in sunlight even in bat form: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuX-CuF8Ps0

Comment: Hotel Transylvania does. But are there any others? I can't find any other mentions.

Answer (score 3):

There are simply too many different versions of Dracula and vampire lore in general to be able to answer this properly.

I can at least say that in Bram Stoker's original *Dracula* novel, Count Dracula does not burn and decay when exposed to sunlight at all. However, his powers are much weaker in daylight. At night he can change his shape (into a bat, for example, or a wolf or even fog/mist) when he wants, as well as at dusk or dawn, but during the day he can only do it at noon.

Comment: The issue is, I can't find ANY lore mentions of it. Regardless of lore. So ignore the original Dracula novel and restrict to lore that actually has burning in sunlight.

Comment: @KatasticVoyage I think it would make more sense if *you* restricted it. In other words, provide specific canons or stories. After all, different vampire stories have different rules.  Make the question objective. Otherwise you're just making everyone guess whether their answer might fit your question.

Comment: I keep running into these problems on SO. I'm trying to gain multiple valid answers. I want a broad understanding of multiple different lores to contrast them. How can I say a specific lore, if I don't know which lores exist?

Comment: @KatasticVoyage So it's essentially a list question :) Simply put, what you are looking for is a list of stories where sunlight harms vampires, and where they can also turn into bats. Then you can decide for yourself which stories work better for you. But certainly you realize that the vampire rules for one story don't affect those of another.

Comment: Yes, that's basically it. I'm trying to gain perspective by contrasting alternative theories of lore.

Comment: @KatasticVoyage Unfortunately it seems like what you're hoping to get out of the site simply isn't what the site is intended for. We're not a discussion forum, we're here to answer very specific, objective questions. We don't allow the kind of open-ended list questions you want to ask.